# DBD::SQLite: database is locked: How to retry?

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi

I use an SQLite database in parallel. Mostly for reading - which means everything works out great. But also for writing and dropping tables. And then suddenly I get this at random times (which indicates a race condition - which is expected running things in parallel):

```
Error: near line 1: database is locked
```

Now I *know* that in 10 ms the database will not be locked, so I would like to just wait 10 ms and try again, but I cannot find a way to catch that error.

How can I catch that error?

Comment: If there's a way of doing it in the SQLite wrappers you're using, you should probably set a "busy timeout" (see [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_busy_timeout)) and SQLite should take care of this. Recommended values seem to be around 5-10s (i.e. a value of 5000-10000).

Comment: The problem seems to be that it is not being regarded as BUSY, but as LOCKED, and that it assumes (wrongly) that the locking cannot go away.

Comment: As can be read here:
http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DatabaseIsLocked

An SQLITE_LOCKED error is distinct from SQLITE_BUSY (5). SQLITE_BUSY means that another database connection (probably in another process) is using the database in a way that prevents you from using it. SQLITE_LOCKED means the source of contention is internal and comes from the same database connection that received the SQLITE_LOCKED error. So waiting and retrying might not help.

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're running into, but I thought I'd throw it out there as you mentioned "in parallel". I ran into this recently and found the problem was that I was using two separate db handles simultaneously under `fork()`. When I refactored my code to pass a single handle around instead and did away with the second one, the issue went away. This is recorded in the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite#DBD::SQLite-and-fork)

Comment: @GeorgMavridis: That's important; thank you. I assumed that a *locked* error was like a file system lock, where it may be applied independently by any process. It sounds like the OP's problem is that all the child processes are using the same database connection, and so locking one another out.

Comment: @stevieb: The documentation that you refer to is very useful, but what it says is contrary to your conclusion. I read *"If you need to `fork()`, `(re)open` a database after you `fork()`. You might also want to tweak `sqlite_busy_timeout` and `sqlite_use_immediate_transaction` (see below), depending on your needs"*. That says to me that the problems will occur if you *don't* have multiple database handles.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

Please take note of [Georg Mavridis' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143514/dbdsqlite-database-is-locked-how-to-retry#comment69492559_41143514) above

It sounds like your child processes are sharing the same database connection and locking out one another

If you want true parallelism then you need to make multiple connections to your database. SQLite will queue requests from separate connections and resolve the conflict for you, unless that behaviour is disabled.

---

You need to design the error handling of your DBI application. There are three options that may be specified in the `connect` call

- `PrintError` — on by default — this will cause a *warning* to be issued if an error arises
- `RaiseError` — off by default — this will cause the process to *die* if an error arises
- `HandleError` — unset by default — this option must be set to a *subroutine reference*, and that subroutine will be called if an error arises

If you expect no database errors then it is probably best to use

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect( ..., { PrintError => 0, RaiseError => 1 } )
```

Then you can enable error handling for parts of the code where something may go wrong and you want to attempt to fix it

The [`DBI` documentation for the `RaiseError` option](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#RaiseError) says this

> If you want to temporarily turn RaiseError off (inside a library function that is likely to fail, for example), the recommended way is like this:
>
> ```
> {
>   local $h->{RaiseError};  # localize and turn off for this block
>   ...
> }
> ```

That way, the `RaiseError` option is implicitly turned back on at the closing brace, and within the block you can check the values returned by `execute`, which says whether the operation was successful, and `errstr`, which gives details of the type of error sustained. You can then write retry code in Perl to do whatever you want

The standard `sleep` call will suspend a process, but has a granularity of one second. If you cannot afford for your program to wait that long between retries, then take a look at the `usleep` function from the [`Time::HiRes`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::HiRes) module, which takes multiples of one microsecond